# Remove all elements that satisfy a predicate from a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a mutable `set` of objects,

```
A = set(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I can construct a *new* set containing only those objects that don't satisfy a predicate ...

```
B = set(x for x in A if not (x % 2 == 0))
```

... but how do I *modify `A` in place* to contain only those objects?  If possible, do this in linear time, without constructing O(n)-sized scratch objects, and without removing anything from `A`, even temporarily, that doesn't satisfy the predicate.

(Integers are used here only to simplify the example.  In the actual code they are `Future` objects and I'm trying to pull out those that have already completed, which is expected to be a small fraction of the total.)

Note that it is not, in general, safe in Python to mutate an object that you are iterating over.  I'm not sure of the precise rules for sets (the documentation doesn't make any guarantee either way).

I only *need* an answer for 3.4+, but will take more general answers.

Comment: O(1) space isn't going to be possible in `O(len(A))` time without screwing with the internals directly. The big underlying reason is that there's no guarantee the hash table won't shrink when you delete something. (CPython happens not to shrink the table on deletion, but other implementations might behave differently.)

Comment: I'd say that if the only space needed is for resizing `A`, then it could be done in amortized O(1) space, since the number of resize operations would be bounded by the original size of the set.

Comment: For clarity, I meant I'd prefer to avoid constructing an O(n)-space scratch object *in my code*; if the interpreter decides to shrink the hash table, oh well (as long as that doesn't mean the *time* complexity becomes quadratic).

Answer (score 5):

(Not actually O(1) due to implementation details, but I'm loathe to delete it as it's quite clean.)

Use `symmetric_difference_update`.

```
>>> A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
>>> A.symmetric_difference_update(x for x in A if not (x % 2))
>>> A
{1, 3, 5}
```

Comment: Not `O(1)` space, though, since it turns the generator into a set internally. I'd probably go with an explicit set argument and `difference_update`.

Comment: That's not O(1) space, either. I'd be surprised if the generator were turned into a set, rather than simply iterated over.

Comment: Indeed, that's not O(1) space, but it's more obvious what the space requirements are. Also, [yes, it makes a set](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/setobject.c#l1647). If it didn't, you'd get a "Set changed size during iteration" error.

Comment: I'm surprised it does that. It doesn't mutate that set at all, it just iterates over it, so there doesn't seem to be any need to make a set in the first place. Looking at `set_update_internal`, it doesn't look like it would be any slower to iterate over the generator in `symmetric_difference_update` than to make a new `set` object. Oh well, it *could* be O(1), but it just isn't.

Comment: I would guess that the reason it makes a set is for duplicate handling. It's trying to ensure `{1, 2}.symmetric_difference_update([1, 1])` doesn't take 1 out and then put it back in.

Comment: Mmm, that's a good point. There's a lot of trade-offs to be made, and this one has the benefit of simplifying the implementation as well; ultimately, you *only* are iterating over a set, regardless of the actual input.

Comment: `.difference_update` *doesn't* make a copy ... and therefore you do get the "Set changed size during iteration" error. `:-(`

Comment: Taking a second look, `difference_update` is actually the one I meant to use, *but* `symmetric_difference_update` works as well because the argument is a subset of the original, rather than an arbitrary set.

Answer (score 3):

With an horrible time complexity (quadratic), but in O(1) space:

```
>>> A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
>>> while modified:
...     modified = False
...     for x in A:
...         if not x%2:
...             A.remove(x)
...             modified = True
...             break
... 
>>> A
{1, 3, 5}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, even this wouldn't be O(1) space on Python implementations that resize the hash table on deletion, since resizing is a linear-space operation.

Comment: Looking at the code of `set_symmetric_difference_update` (and `set_discard_entry`), it does not seem to rehash.

Answer (score 2):

On the very specific use case you showed, there is a way to do this in `O(1)` space, but it doesn't generalize very well to sets containing anything other than `int` objects:

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

for i in range(min(A), max(A) + 1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        A.discard(i)
```

It also wastes time since it will check numbers that aren't even in the set. For anything other than `int` objects, I can't yet think of a way to do this without creating an intermediate `set` or container of some sort.

For a more general solution, it would be better to simply initially construct your `set` using the predicate (if you don't need to use the `set` for anything else first). Something like this:

```
def items():
    # maybe this is a file or a stream or something,
    # where ever your initial values are coming from.
    for thing in source:  
        yield thing

def predicate(item):
    return bool(item)

A = set(item for item in items() if predicate(item))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual objects in the set are not integers, and whether they satisfy the predicate changes over time (they are `Future` objects and I want to remove the ones that have completed).

Comment: @zwol Interesting. You could maybe try something with the `weakref` module (like a `weakset`). That way it would disappear from the set automatically. Or you could use the `add_done_callback` to add a callback that would automatically remove the `Future` from the set once it is complete. You would probably need to use a `Lock` primitive since threading or processes are involved. Even still it should simplify your logic instead of effectively polling the set instance.

Comment: The larger problem is a "don't quit before all the side effects have happened" problem, so I rather like the `add_done_callback` idea.  I'm going to leave this as a question about sets in general, though.

Answer (score 1):

to maintain the use use of memory constant this is the only thing that come to my mind

```
def filter_Set(predicate,origen:set) -> set:
    resul = set()
    while origen:
        elem = origen.pop()
        if predicate( elem ):
            resul.add( elem )
    return resul

def filter_Set_inplace(predicate,origen:set):
    resul = set()
    while origen:
        elem = origen.pop()
        if predicate( elem ):
            resul.add( elem )
    while resul:
        origen.add(resul.pop())
```

with this functions I move elems from one set to the other keeping only those that satisfied the predicate